# How can I ignore TypeScript errors when adding script tags via react-helmet?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-helmet

The following tsx code generates TypeScript errors. `//@ts-ignore` doesn't work.

```
<Helmet>
  <script>
    (function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':
    new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
    j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=
    'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
    })(window,document,'script','dataLayer','GTM-*******');
  </script>
</Helmet>
```

[image]

The following code works, but I would like to use a child `<script>` tag vs the `script` component property.

```
<Helmet
  script={[
    {
      type: 'application/javascript',
      innerHTML: '(function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({\'gtm.start\':new Date().getTime(),event:\'gtm.js\'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!=\'dataLayer\'?\'&l=\'+l:\'\';j.async=true;j.src=\'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id=\'+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);})(window,document,\'script\',\'dataLayer\',\'GTM-*******\');'
    }
  ]}
/>
```

Comment: ts-ignore has to work, maybe u need to add this on multiple lines, or xclude this file in ts.config in exclude propery

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figured it out thanks to https://github.com/nfl/react-helmet/issues/334#issuecomment-413319383.

```js
<Helmet>
  <script>
    {`
      alert('BOOM');
    `} 
  </script>
</Helmet>
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this script have to be embedded as part of your Component heap?

I faced a similar issue when using YouTube's iframe API and the solution was to create the script element and reference the javascript objects created once they exist (if you need to do that, looks like you literally just want to import some JS). I didn't need to create a react component for this unless there were visual elements I wanted to manage.

// GoogleTagManager.ts

```
export class GoogleTagManager {
  someVariable: someVariableType = null 

  constructor () {
    const script: HTMLScriptElement = <HTMLScriptElement>document.createElement('script')

    script.src = '[URL_TO_JS_FILE]'

    script.onload = (): void => console.log('loaded google tag manager')

    document.body.appendChild(script)
  }

  WaitForVariable (): void {
    let timeout: number

    const OnTimeout = (): void => {
      if (timeout) {
        clearTimeout(timeout)
      }

      if (typeof [TARGET_VARIABLE] !== 'undefined') {
        this.someVariable = [TARGET_VARIABLE]
        return
      }

      timeout = setTimeout(OnTimeout, 1000)
    }
  }
}
```

If you want to display some information then you could turn this into a React Component and move the constructor logic to componentDidMount. Alternatively I would consider sending any resultant data to a store and having a separate component for rendering the resultant data.

Answer (score -1):

With caution, you can use [dangerouslySetInnerHTML](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html) like so:

```
<script
  dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
    __html: `
    (function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':
    new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
    j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=
    'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
    })(window,document,'script','dataLayer','GTM-*******');
`,
  }}
/>
```

But be careful of [cross-site scripting (XSS) attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting).